# How to display a gif on a javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a bingo sort of web page and I would like to have a canvas with a gif in the corner on a big canvas so I can draw next to it. I could not find a way to display a gif like this so I split the big canvas up into 2 canvas. But now they are just all next to each other or under each other. I can't get all the object to basically push up as much as possible.[this picture hopefully explains what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tKA.png) I kind of don't want to break the gif up into frames as it is like 190 frames. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you had a look at CSS flexbox functionality? Seems to me it might help you.

Comment: I will have a look at that